# How can I view a different tab using a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio I have created a windows form with a tab menu.Can I use a button to switch between the tabs and how would I do that?

Comment: The SelectedIndex or SelectedTab properties of the Tab control might be of interest to you.

Comment: I am confident you'll find good answers if you Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows Forms, here is an example of switching to 2nd tab page in a tab control named tabcontrol1. Remember that the first tab page has an index of zero. Of course, you should have a tab control with 2 pages to use this code.

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = this.tabControl1.TabPages[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
    }
```

Set a conditional statement and do the `tabControl1.SelectedIndex--` to switch back to previous tab.

OR use two buttons

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex--;
    }
```